# Latitude longitude in ionic application

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm tried to get latitude and longitude in my current location for the mobile application with using ionic framework. But It's get the exact value in browser but when I build in mobile then I found undefined latitude longitude. I used $cordovaGeolocation plugin. Here is the code below,

```
GetCurrentAddress();
        $timeout(function() {
            var data = {
                longitude: $scope.longitude,
                latitude: $scope.latitude
            }
            // console.log(data)
        }, 10000);

    // Get the current address
    function GetCurrentAddress() {

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

            var posOptions = {
                enableHighAccuracy: false,
                timeout: 50000,
                maximumAge: 0
            };
            $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var long = position.coords.longitude;

                $scope.latitude = lat;
                $scope.longitude = long;

            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

        });

    };
```

I've tried a lot but could not find any solution. Is there any alternative way to get latitude longitude in my location for the mobile application using ionic framework?

Comment: check your device weather you have allow **your current device location** in you device keept `on` or not .

Comment: is location enabled for the device ?

Comment: yes,device location is enabled.

Comment: is the error callback called then ? . where do you get undefined lat/lng

Comment: I also used error callback but its response is always undefined.

Comment: this one https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation ?

Comment: I think it'll be work for me..I'll try this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113884/discussion-between-afroza-yasmin-and-shubhank).